# JS function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

When the button "GenQR" is clicked nothing happens.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLjaz/)**

**Console**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: JSQR is not defined(index):26
myqr (index):26
(anonymous function) (index):51
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.0.js:4371
elemData.handle
```

---

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="qr"/>GenQR</button>
```

**qr.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DomContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('qr').addEventListener('click', myqr);
});
(function myqr() {
    var qr = new JSQR();
    var code = new qr.Code();

    code.encodeMode = code.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE;
    code.version = code.DEFAULT;

    code.errorCorrection = code.ERROR_CORRECTION.H;

    var input = new qr.Input();
    input.dataType = input.DATA_TYPE.TEXT;

    input.data = 'test';

    var matrix = new qr.Matrix(input, code);


    matrix.scale = 10;
    matrix.margin = 10;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', matrix.pixelWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', matrix.pixelWidth);
    canvas.getContext('2d').fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    matrix.draw(canvas, 0, 0);

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
})();
```

Comment: What is your `min.js` file?

Comment: `JSQR is not defined` is a clear enough error. What makes you think it should be defined?

Answer (score 1):

In your JS function called myqr(), you have the following statement:

```
var qr = new JSQR();
```

However, nowhere in your code has JSQR been defined, Hence the browser doesn't know what you're talking about and throws an error.

Also, nothing happens on the click of a button because when the above mentioned error takes place the function quits...

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code and fiddle you provided. The first major one being that jsqr isn't defined as the others have mentioned. You need to set the external reference to the jsqr library (http://code.jsqr.de/jsqr-0.2-min.js) otherwise it doesn't know what that library is.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mcfarljw/n9PbR/

The second issue is you've called a self invoking function that fires when the script is loaded and thus won't be fired when the click event happens.

```
(function myqr() {
    //your code here
})();
```

You should just make it a function like this:

```
function myqr() {
    //your code here
}
```

Lastly, you've wrapped your click event listener in a DomContentLoaded listener. This isn't needed when using jsfiddle they way you have it configured, because the script is already set to run onLoad. So you can remove it for the fiddle example, but you'll need to put something like it in in your other local code.